# How do I control the setInterval event?

Tags: javascript

I am designing a button. The text on the button is "run" at the beginning. If I click it the text turns into "stop" and it triggers a setInterval event. However, I have trouble about how to stop this event.
In the following code, I declare run variable at the beginning; in the if statement, I set it to a setInteval, but the run variable shows undefined in the else branch, making the clearInterval function not working as expected. How do I solve this problem?

```
$("#run").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var run;
   if($this.text() === "run"){
      run = setInterval(()=>{
           model.run();
       },50);
       $this.text("stop");
   }
   else{
       clearInterval(run);
       $this.text("run");
   }});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handler function of your `click` event is being run every time you click. That also means that any variable in that function that you define, is being redefined. Put your `run` variable outside of the click function scope.

```
var run;

$("#run").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.text() === "run"){
      run = setInterval(()=>{
           model.run();
       },50);
       $this.text("stop");
   }
   else{
       clearInterval(run);
       $this.text("run");
   }
});
```

Or if you don't want any global variables hanging around, use closures.

```
$("#run").click((function(){
  var run;
  return function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text() === "run"){
      run = setInterval(()=>{
        model.run();
      },50);
      $this.text("stop");
    }
    else{
      clearInterval(run);
      $this.text("run");
    }
  }
}()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

```js
$("#run").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var run;
   if($this.text() === "run"){
      run = setInterval(()=>{
          // model.run();
       },50);
       $this.text("stop");
   }
   else{
       clearInterval(run);
       $this.text("run");
   }});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="run">run</button>
```

Comment: The problem is that the text will change, yet the model won't stop.

Comment: You have not added the model's code here. please add it as well.